# Passing variable to `expect` in bash array

Tags: linux, bash, variables, for-loop, expect

I am trying to use a FOR loop to iterate over IP addresses (in a bash array), logs in, runs a script and then exits. The array is called ${INSTANCE_IPS[@]}. The following code doesn't work though, as `expect` doesn't seem to be able to accept the variable $instance.

```
for instance in ${INSTANCE_IPS[@]}
  do
  echo $instance
  /usr/bin/expect -c '
  spawn ssh root@$instance;
  expect "?assword: ";
  send "<password>\r";
  expect "# ";
  send ". /usr/local/bin/bootstrap.sh\r";
  expect "# ";
  send "exit\r" '
done
```

However, `expect` complains with:

```
can't read "instance": no such variable
    while executing
"spawn ssh root@$instance"
```

There is another question on stackoverflow located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928226/how-to-pass-shell-script-variable-into-expect-script), that uses environmental variables to achieve this, however it doesn't allow me to iterate through different IP addresses like I can in an array.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15422824/191246

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with quoting.  Single quotes surrounding the whole block don't let Bash expand variables (`$instance`).

You need to switch to double quotes.  But then, double quotes inside double quotes are not allowed (unless you escape them), so we are better off using single quotes with `expect` strings.

Try instead:

```
for instance in ${INSTANCE_IPS[@]}
  do
  echo $instance
  /usr/bin/expect -c "
  spawn ssh root@$instance;
  expect '?assword: ';
  send '<password>\r';
  expect '# ';
  send '. /usr/local/bin/bootstrap.sh\r';
  expect '# ';
  send 'exit\r' "
done
```

Comment: I actually needed to comment out thge "s, as it wasn't interpreting the \r character. All working now. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
for instance in ${INSTANCE_IPS[&]} ;  do
    echo $instance
    /usr/bin/expect -c '
    spawn ssh root@'$instance' "/usr/local/bin/bootstrap.sh"
    expect "password:"
    send "<password>\r"
    expect eof'
done
```

From the ssh man page:

`If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.`

Specifying a command means expect doesn't have to wait for `#` to execute your program, then wait for another `#` just to send the command `exit`. Instead, when you specify a command to ssh, it executes that command; it exits when done; and then ssh automatically closes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, put the value in the environment and expect can find it there

```
for instance in ${INSTANCE_IPS[&]} ;  do
    echo $instance
    the_host=$instance /usr/bin/expect -c '
        spawn ssh root@$env(the_host) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, and one of many, but I've been working on `expect` for several days. For anyone who comes across this, I belive I've found a doable solution to the problem of passing `bash` variables inside an `expect -c` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
password="TopSecret"

read -d '' exp << EOF
set user "John Doe"
puts "\$user"
puts "$password"
EOF

expect -c "$exp"
```

Please note that escaping quotations are typically a cited issue (as @Roberto Reale stated above), which I've solved using a `heredoc` `EOF` method, *before* passing the bash-variable-evaluated string to `expect -c`. In contrast to escaping quotes, **all native `expect` variables will need to be escaped with `\$`** (I'm not here to solve *all* first-world problems--my afternoon schedule is slightly crammed), but this should greatly simplify the problem with little effort. Let me know if you find any issues with this proof of concept.

tl;tr: Been creating an [`expect`] daemon script with user authentication and just figured this out *after* I spent a whole day creating separated bash/expect scripts, encrypting my prompted password (via bash) with a different `/dev/random` salt each iteration, saving the encrypted password to a temp file and passing the salt to the expect script (highly discouraging anyone from easily discovering the password via `ps`, but not preventative since the expect script could be replaced). Now I should be able to effectively keep it in memory instead.